# Poetry in Docker creates venv despite `poetry env use system`

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-venv, python-poetry

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.12-bookworm

# Configure Poetry
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry
ENV POETRY_VENV=/opt/poetry-venv
ENV POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/opt/.cache

# Install Poetry isolated from the system
RUN python -m venv $POETRY_VENV \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install -U pip setuptools \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

# Add Poetry to PATH
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${POETRY_VENV}/bin"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

# Configure Poetry to install project dependencies system-wide
RUN poetry env use system && poetry install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "djadja.asgi:application"]
```

When I do `docker run -it bash ...` and inspect the container, everything looks and works exactly as expected (`pip list`, `poetry env info`, `which uvicorn`).

But when I run with a simple compose.yml (nothing there, just `build .`) it outputs the error:

```
web-1 | Creating virtualenv djadja-VA82Wl8V-py3.12 in /opt/.cache/virtualenvs
web-1 | Command not found: uvicorn
```

I've tried:

`poetry config virtualenvs.create false`

`poetry config virtualenvs.in-project false`

`CMD ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "uvicorn", ...]`

`CMD ["poetry", "run", "uvicorn", ...]`

Please don't suggest workarounds like installing poetry directly to the system, using venv for the project dependencies, or using multi-stage builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your project looks like this:

```
├── djadja
│   └── asgi.py
├── Dockerfile
└── pyproject.toml
```

`Dockerfile` (Not convinced that we need a virtual environment in the image, so going without! See below for implementation using virtual environment.)

```
FROM python:3.12-bookworm

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.8.1

RUN pip install -U pip setuptools && \
    pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY pyproject.toml .

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-root

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "djadja.asgi:application", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Not sure what your `pyproject.toml` has in it, so using `--no-root` option to `poetry` to install dependencies.

`pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "example-project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A minimal example project with Poetry."
authors = ["Your Name <youremail@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
fastapi = "^0.65.2"
uvicorn = "^0.13.4"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

[image]

`Dockerfile` (Using virtual environment.)

```
FROM python:3.12-bookworm

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV POETRY_VENV=/usr/src/app/.venv

ENV PATH="${POETRY_VENV}/bin:${PATH}:"

RUN python -m venv $POETRY_VENV && \
    pip install -U pip setuptools && \
    pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true && \
    poetry install --no-root

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD uvicorn djadja.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

Comment: Dumbest thing, I was using docker run / docker build and forgot to tag appropriately for docker-compose (`djadja-web`) or just build with `dcupd --build`, 

The `package-mode = false` so it works without `--no-root` before copying the source code.

Thank you for such a clear example.